# Why isn't "sudo npm install -g express" working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I am running Mac OSX 10.9.2,
Node v0.10.28,
NPM 1.4.9

I am doing the expressworks exercises

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

This command seemingly works but when I run the code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/home', function(req,res) {
res.end('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I get an error that says that node cannot find the module express.

I got it to work when I installed express locally with just

```
npm install express
```

Can someone tell me if I did anything wrong in the first command?

Comment: What is your `$NODE_PATH`?  And do you know where the `express` module was installed?

Comment: You can't `require` globally installed module in `node.js`.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/faq.html#I-installed-something-globally-but-I-can-t-require-it

Comment: Thank Avery, that explains it.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny That is not true, you definitely can as long as your paths haven't been screwed up.